# find all possible combinations of arraylists java

Tags: java, arraylist

i need to find all combos of the iceCream and toppings lists and this code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class IceCream {

    public long printMenu( )
    {
        String iceCream[] = {" ", "chocolate", "vanilla", "strawberry"};
        String toppings[] = {" ", "sprinkles", "whipped cream", "chocolate chips"};

        ArrayList<String> menuList = new ArrayList<String>();
        long menu_num = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < iceCream.length; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < toppings.length; y++)
            {
                menu_num++;
                menuList.add(iceCream[x] + " " +  toppings[y]);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(menuList);
        return menu_num;
    }

    public static void main( String [ ] args ) {
        IceCream obj = new IceCream( );
        long count = obj.printMenu( );
        System.out.println(count);
        assert count == 32;
    }

            }
```

outputs

```
[   ,   sprinkles,   whipped cream,   chocolate chips, chocolate  , chocolate sprinkles, chocolate whipped cream, chocolate chocolate chips, vanilla  , vanilla sprinkles, vanilla whipped cream, vanilla chocolate chips, strawberry  , strawberry sprinkles, strawberry whipped cream, strawberry chocolate chips]
16

Process finished with exit code 0
```

i need to be able to have more than one topping on each ice cream and print out 32 combos total. any help is appreciated

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I can't figure out how to have more than one topping for each flavor of ice cream in the array

Comment: You have printed the 16 possible combinations of toppings. If you combine that with the four ice cream flavors (including blank), that's 4 x 16 = 64

Comment: A) I wouldn't use space as distinct name, that is super hard to read correctly. Why not call that default cream/topping or something  B) I don't get it. 4 types of cream, with 4 different toppings. So you get 4 X 4... 16 combinations?! Why do expect 32?

Comment: @Tarik no, Alex printed 4 x 4 combinations of cream and topping. The ice cream type is already part of the output. No idea why Alex expects 32 pairs, or you think it should be 64.

Comment: Note: dropping your question to then walk away isn't appreciated. The idea is that you stay around, for example to react to feedback and clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there.

In your code, you have the following:

- a loop to loop through the ice cream flavors
- a loop to loop through the first layer of toppings

But you are having trouble trying to put the **second** topping on there, yes? If so, would it not make sense to have yet another loop for the second layer of toppings?

```
    for (int x = 0; x < iceCream.length; x++)
    {

        for (int y = 0; y < toppings.length; y++)
        {

            for (int z = 0; z < toppings.length; z++)
            {

                menu_num++;
                menuList.add(iceCream[x] + " " +  toppings[y] + " " toppings[z]);

            }

        }

    }
```

Now, if you run this, you will notice that there are some duplicates and reorderings. If you need to get rid of those, let me know.

Comment: Where does it say that the goal is to have two toppings?

Comment: Touche. The original poster requested more than 1 topping, so I am providing a way to achieve that goal.

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to find out different toppings combination for each ice cream type, the ideal way is to use Guava's [Sets.powerset(Set set)](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#powerSet-java.util.Set-).

**Sets.powerset(Set set)** will return all the combination of subsets of the set.
In your case you can generate a powerset as below,

```
String toppings[] = {" ", "sprinkles", "whipped cream", "chocolate chips"};

// Creating a set from toppings array
Set<String> set = Sets.newHashSet(Arrays.asList(toppings));  

// powerSet to store all subsets of a set 
// The powerset will contain all the combination of toppings as subsets
// Ex: [ , whipped cream, sprinkles], [ , whipped cream, sprinkles, chocolate chips], ...
Set<Set<String>> powerSet = Sets.powerSet(set);
```

Now that you have the **powerSet** with subset of combinations, you can iterate over and convert each subset to a combination of topping strings as below,

```
// This set is to concatinate the entries of the subset (of the powerset) and store as a string
Set<String> toppingsCombinationSet = Sets.newHashSet();

for (Set<String> s : powerSet) {
    String toppings = "";
    for (String topping : s) {
        toppings = toppings.trim() + " " + topping.trim();
    }
    toppingsCombinationSet.add(toppings);       
}
```

Finally you can combine the ice cream type to the combination of toppings as below,

```
// Combine the ice Cream to the toppings combination
// Whitespaces need to be removed as it doesn't make any sense to have values like : "sprinkles chocolate chips" (without ice cream type)
for (int x = 0; x < iceCream.length; x++) { 
    if (!" ".equals(iceCream[x])) {
        for (String topping : toppingsCombinationSet) {
            if (!" ".equals(topping)) {
                String s = (iceCream[x].trim() + " " +  topping.trim()).trim();
                menuList.add(s);
            }    

        }
            
    }
}
```